# aspdotnetstorefront - (!SITE_NAME!) not working on pop up layout

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

(!SITE_NAME!)  and other variables don't seem to work when calling a topic with the t2-topicname.aspx formatting. It does work with t-topicname.aspx.  Any fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the page driver2.aspx doesn't inherit from `SkinBase`, which does all of the token replacement. The easiest way around this would be to modify driver2.aspx.cs so that it inherits from SkinBase but uses a different (empty) master page template.